# Как выбрать наибольший элемент массива?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть такая задача - отследить последнее сообщение в чате. Я решил отслеживать его по времени, собираю массив, осталось оттуда только вытащить самое максимальное значение, так как я ещё новичок, в некоторых вещах путаюсь. Данный скрипт выводит -Infinity, и гугл подводит, хотя вопрос, я понимаю, что простой.

```
 var timestamp = {};
    $('a.times').each(function(i, el){
        var val = $(el).attr('data-temp');
        var name = $(el).attr('data-cgid');
        timestamp[name] = Number(val);
    });

    var maxTime = Math.max.apply(timestamp);

    console.log(maxTime);
```

Comment: а как собирает  откуда

Comment: у сообщений есть же  контейнер может отобрать все элементы  с классвом и выбрать последний и это убдет то что Вам надо

Comment: типа  var T = document.getElementByClassName(class); var result = T[T.length - 1]. var text = result .innerHTML

Comment: Дело в том, что сам чат писал не я, мне просто поставили задачу - сделать оповещалку, а код написан так, что каждые 5 секунд чат обновляется и отображаются данные из бд, если они изменились, то должно быть оповещение. Именно поэтому я и делаю выборку по времени, чтобы сравнить значения и если новое больше, то вызвать аудио. Благодарю за ответ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прежде всего, как сказал @Санитариум лучше хранить сообщения чата в структуре данных. Что же касательно вашего кода, то в нём есть ошибки

1. Math.max.apply(null, numArray); работает с массивом, вы же объявили и используете timestamp как объект
2. Соответсвенно и записывать данные в эту переменную надо через push
3. Для доступа к атрибуту data у jquery есть свой метод.

Вот как можно переработать ваш код.

```js
var timestamp = [];
$('a.times').each(function(i, el) {
  var val = $(el).data('temp');
  var name = $(el).data('cgid');
  timestamp.push(Number(val));
});

var maxTime = Math.max.apply(null, timestamp);

console.log(maxTime);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="times" data-temp="123451" data-cgid="1"></a>
<a class="times" data-temp="123452" data-cgid="2"></a>
<a class="times" data-temp="123454" data-cgid="4"></a>
<a class="times" data-temp="123453" data-cgid="3"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Рекомендую использовать JQuery [.last()](https://api.jquery.com/last/)

Comment: нужно было не последнее, а максимальное по величине значение

Comment: @KirillBulgakov Ну я как понимаю в чате обычно последовательно по времени публикуются сообщения и самое нижнее самое новое (максимальное по времени)?